# How to convert Whitebox .dep files for use in e-Cognition?

Tags: ecognition, whitebox-gat

Could you explain me how can I convert .dep files into correct files to work in e-Cognition?

I’ve exported the file in .sdat and .sgrd form using Export Layer, but I lose a lot of resolution. Any suggestion?

Comment: What are .dep files? (what software produces them)

Comment: Is the file creates by Withebox when you create an image from LAS file

Comment: I don't have a copy of e-Cognition available. If you can list for me the options that it has for importing raster images, I can tell you what your best avenue for Whitebox export/e-Cog import would be. P.S. the .dep file is the ASCII header of a Whitebox raster and must be paired with the binary data .tas file.

Comment: Finally, I’ve exported the file in .sdat and .sgrd form using Export Layer, but I loose a lot of resolution. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was put on hold. The PO clearly stated that .dep files are associated with Whitebox in the title and used the whitebox-gat tag, so it should be pretty evident. The question itself is valid and there are plenty of similar questions on the GIS.SE that haven't been closed.